# I am compiling the gazebo_naoqi_control for NAO on Gazebo but getting compilation Error

Tags: ros, gazebo, naoqi, nao, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am compiling the nao_gazebo (https://github.com/costashatz/nao_gazebo) package for NAO simulation on Gazebo but i am getting compilation error on catkin_make .

Error is :

```
In file included from /home/saleem/catkin_ws/src/nao_gazebo/gazebo_naoqi_control/src/gazebo_naoqi_control_plugin.cpp:24:0:
/home/saleem/catkin_ws/src/nao_gazebo/gazebo_naoqi_control/include/gazebo_naoqi_control/gazebo_naoqi_control_plugin.h:45:31: fatal error: alnaosim/alnaosim.h: No such file or directory 
#include 
^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nao_gazebo/gazebo_naoqi_control/CMakeFiles/gazebo_naoqi_control.dir/src/gazebo_naoqi_control_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nao_gazebo/gazebo_naoqi_control/CMakeFiles/gazebo_naoqi_control.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228924/i-am-compiling-the-gazebo_naoqi_control-for-nao-on-gazebo-but-getting-compilation-error./) by [saleem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26204/saleem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have the [Aldebaran NAO Simulator SDK](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/ref/simulator-sdk/index.html) installed and properly set up. There you'll find the missing header file.

Also, check out the Readme of the package you try to build, this actually tells you in the `Building/Compiling` section that you have to configure some environment variables...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saleem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26204/saleem/) on 2016-03-14**:
I followed the steps for Building/Compiling. I am still getting the error.

My SDK path is -- ~/naoqi/simulator-sdk-2.1.2.17-linux64 -- so i have added these envoirnment variables

AL_SIM_DIR = ~/naoqi/simulator-sdk-2.1.2.17-linux64

AL_DIR = ~/naoqi/simulator-sdk-2.1.2.17-linux64

Any Help?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-14**:
where did you add/export them? added to `.bashrc`? only in one terminal? Did you compile in the terminal where you set this? Also, does te path contain the `include` folder directly? Check out [this fiile]  for where the paths should "end". Also, try replacing `~`  with `/home/saleem`.

**Comment by [saleem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26204/saleem/) on 2016-03-14**:
I have added them in .bashrc file. No path doesn't contain include folder directly. My AL_DIR= ~/naoqi/simulator-sdk-2.1.2.17-linux64 -- no include in the environment variables. Do i need to add include folder in AL_DIR?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-14**:
if you check out [this file](https://github.com/costashatz/nao_gazebo/blob/master/gazebo_naoqi_control/cmake/FindNAOqiSIM.cmake#L46) (now with the link hopefully working), you see it expects to have the `include` folder directly after your `AL_SIM_DIR`, this is `${AL_SIM_DIR}/include` should exist.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-14**:
Also (long shot, but just to be safe ;-) ). Did you source the `.bashrc` after adding the environment variables there?

**Comment by [saleem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26204/saleem/) on 2016-03-14**:
I have hardcoded the include files in the headers. Now it has been compiled and motion and stiffness commands are working. Hoping that it will not crash for any other commands.

Thankss a lot mig for your help. Will get back to you for any other help. :)